# display table and table-cell not like <table> and <td> when having only one cell

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have the same displaying as using (the balise table> and td>) by using the css display table and  table-cell  property. .

i don't want that the cell have 100% width of the table when having only one cell at row.

Here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <style>
         .a{
         width: 400px;
         display:table;
         border-collapse:separate;
         border-spacing: .76923rem .76923rem;
         }
         .b{
         display:table-cell;
         padding: .76923rem .13923rem;
         width: 50%;
         vertical-align: middle;
         background:#333856;
         }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class= "a">
         <div class= "b"> 
            aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa
         </div>
         <div class= "b"> 
            bbbbbbb bbbb
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class= "a">
         <div class= "b"> 
            cccc cccc
         </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can't you just add an empty `div`?

Comment: i can't because the content is very dynamic . is better for me to find a solution using only css without changing the html structure

Comment: Why do you need to use tables? Flex would make it a lot easier.

Comment: flex is not supported  By IE less than 11 for this reason i m using table

Comment: @abderrahimesanadi Actually it is supported by IE 10, just with an older spec; which I think you can handle with prefixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove `display:table`, it works as expected.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <style>
         .a{
         width: 400px;
         border-collapse:separate;
         border-spacing: .76923rem .76923rem;
         }
         .b{
         display:table-cell;
         padding: .76923rem .13923rem;
         width: 50%;
         vertical-align: middle;
         background:#333856;
         }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class= "a">
         <div class= "b"> 
            aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa
         </div>
         <div class= "b"> 
            bbbbbbb bbbb
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class= "a">
         <div class= "b"> 
            cccc cccc
         </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```